# Python - array indexing, why is the double bracket necessary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

I was wondering whether anyone could explain to me the syntax of this line of code

a[[1, 6, 7]] = 10
where a is an array.

The need for the double brackets is what is confusing me the most

Answer (score 2):

Indexing with `1, 6, 7` (*i.e.* `a[1, 6, 7]`) would suggest you are **indexing along three separate axes** of `a` which is not what you are looking for. This corresponds to the following assignment:

```
a[1][6][7] = 10
```

Indexing with `[1, 6, 7]` (*i.e.* `a[[1, 6, 7]]`), means you are indexing **a single** axis with a *list*. Essentially accessing multiple different values of *array* `a`. This corresponds to the following assignments:

```
a[1] = 10
a[6] = 10
a[7] = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is a `numpy.array`, the syntax `a[x, y, z]` has another use, which is to select from a 3-dimensional array the element at that position. In your case, `a` seems to be a 1-dimensional array, so you can only select by `x` (that is `a[x]`, and for example `a[x,y]` would be incorrect since there is no second dimension)

And that '`x`' value can be either just one index (for instance `a[0]`, here the `x` is an **integer**) or multiple ones  (for instance `a[[0,1]]`, and here `x` is a **list of integers**).